# Display subcategories belonging to a category when the category is clicked in October CMS

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

I implemented nested relationship in October CMS. I am done setting up all relationships, but the list page shows categories and subcategories this way.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Agriculture and Apparel are the categories. Is there a way to render the subcategories when the category is clicked instead of everything showing on one page?

Comment: can you be more specific `is there a way to render the subcategories when the category is clicked` => on same page or in next page, or using js hide show.

Comment: The next page not on the same page. something similar to category->subacategory->products